# Am I required to buy a train ticket in order to use the locker facility at Zurich station?

Tags: luggage-storage, train-stations, zurich

I will be traveling to Zurich by bus (Flixbus) and I'm going to need the locker facility at Zurich main station to keep my luggage.  Am I required to buy a train ticket to use the locker facility?

Answer (score 3):

No, the lockers are available to everybody.

Answer (score 2):

The lockers are coin operated.

If the luggage does not fit a locker you can leave it at the left luggage office.

If you leave the luggage in a locker for too long it will be moved to the left luggage office anyway.

There is more information in [this discussion](https://www.myswissalps.com/forum/topic/left-luggage-at-zurich-hb).

Left luggage does not generally need a train ticket. You might have arrived by train and surrendered the ticket, but want to store luggage while you sight see, for example.